# Phpmyadmin displays a blank page when logged in on Zend Server CE?

Tags: windows-7, phpmyadmin, zend-server-ce

I have installed Zend Server CE on Windows 7. Everything works great, but when I go to phpMyAdmin and login, it displays a blank page.

It installs with no password and the username root.
It seems able to login, but the page is just blank.

Has anybody else had this problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: A blank page usually means a fatal error occurred but error reporting is not set to display that error. Look at the server's PHP error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Zend Server CE with PHP 5.2 worked for me. It doesn't give me a blank page for some reason. I had Zend Server CE with PHP 5.3 installed.